# GPU rendering not working after upgrading

Tags: rendering, gpu

My pc will not render in any mode using the GPU after upgrading from 2.8 to 2.9

My GPU drivers are up to date and worked until I upgraded. My GPU is a AMD Radeon R9 390.
It has been running smoothly with blender until recently.

My driver version for the GPU is 20.45.27.02-210118a-363193E-RadeonSoftwareAdrenalin2020

Here is a screen shot with the current version of Blender

[image]